# Synchronizing an ERWin model with a Visual Studio 2008 GDR 2/2010 db project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, version-control, database-project

I am looking for options to get our vast collection of DB objects across many DBs into source control (TFS 2010). Once we succeed here, we will work toward generating our alter scripts for a particular DB change via TFS build.

The problem is, our data architecture group is responsible for maintaining the DB objects (excluding SPs), and they work within a model centric process, via ERWin. What this means, is that they maintain the DBs via ERWin models, and generate alters from them that are used to release changes.

In order to achieve our goal of getting the DB objects (not just the ERWin models) into TFS, I believe the best option is to do this via Visual Studio DB projects. From what I can tell, there is very little urgency for CA to continue supporting an integration between ERWin and Visual Studio, that no longer works as of Visual Studio 2008 DB Ed. GDR. If I have been mislead in this regard, please feel free to set me straight.

One potential solution is to:

1. Perform changes in the ERWin model.
2. Take the alter script generated from ERWin, and import the script into the appropriate Visual Studio DB project, updating the objects in the in the DB project
3. Check the changed objects in the DB project into TFS.
4. TFS Build executes to generate the alter scripts that will be used to push the changes through our release process.

My question is, is this solution viable, or are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds quite cumbersome to me, as you've essentially got a clash between two different ways of working, which you're trying to resolve.

How do the data architecture group work? Do they use the version control in ERWin, or what process do they have for managing versions?

I would look at integrating this into your build process, so the alter scripts are retrieved from that, instead of having a manual merge process into DB objects.

This could be expanded further, to integrate the two teams source control systems, allowing you to see one view of database objects going forward.